# asp.net Core troubleshooting email verification with send grid

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, sendgrid

**edit: This is resolved see bottom**

I was walking through the documentation here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/accconfirm?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio#debug

to try to allow email verification but I can't get the email to send. I made sure that I turned the setting off so other things besides my code can run. (tools-> options -> debugging ->general -> uncheck box)

I steped through with the debbuger and the line

```
 return   client.SendEmailAsync(msg);
```

gets called.

I cant see anything in the output that looks like its wrong but I could be wrong, but I don't even know what I'm looking for. I've tried goint through all of the troubleshooting listed at the above link.

here is my register,emailsender and startup pages.

register

```
        public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(string returnUrl = null)
        {
            returnUrl = returnUrl ?? Url.Content("~/");
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var user = new IdentityUser { UserName = Input.Email, Email = Input.Email };
                var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, Input.Password);
                if (result.Succeeded)
                {
                    _logger.LogInformation("User created a new account with password.");

                    var code = await _userManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user);
                    var callbackUrl = Url.Page(
                        "/Account/ConfirmEmail",
                        pageHandler: null,
                        values: new { userId = user.Id, code = code },
                        protocol: Request.Scheme);

                    await _emailSender.SendEmailAsync(Input.Email, "Confirm your email",
                        $"Please confirm your account by <a href='{HtmlEncoder.Default.Encode(callbackUrl)}'>clicking here</a>.");

                  //  await _signInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false);
                    return LocalRedirect(returnUrl);
                }
                foreach (var error in result.Errors)
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, error.Description);
                }
            }

            // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
            return Page();
        }
```

email sender

```
 public class EmailSender : IEmailSender
    {
        public EmailSender(IOptions<AuthMessageSenderOptions> optionsAccessor)
        {
            Options = optionsAccessor.Value;
        }

        public AuthMessageSenderOptions Options { get; } //set only via Secret Manager

        public Task SendEmailAsync(string email, string subject, string message)
        {
            return Execute(Options.SendGridKey, subject, message, email);
        }

        public Task Execute(string apiKey, string subject, string message, string email)
        {
            var client = new SendGridClient(apiKey);
            var msg = new SendGridMessage()
            {
                From = new EmailAddress("sam.wakeman@gmail.com", "Samuel Wakeman"),
                Subject = subject,
                PlainTextContent = message,
                HtmlContent = message
            };
            msg.AddTo(new EmailAddress(email));

            msg.SetClickTracking(false, false);

            return   client.SendEmailAsync(msg);
        }
    }
```

startup

```
public class Startup

    {
        private string _moviesApiKey = null;



        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {

            _moviesApiKey = Configuration["Movies:ServiceApiKey"];

            services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
            {
                // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
                options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
                options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
            });

            services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(
                    Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
            services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>(config =>
            {
                config.SignIn.RequireConfirmedEmail = true;
            })
              .AddDefaultUI(UIFramework.Bootstrap4)
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();

            // requires
            // using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI.Services;
            // using WebPWrecover.Services;
            services.AddTransient<IEmailSender, EmailSender>();
            services.Configure<AuthMessageSenderOptions>(Configuration);

            services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);

        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseCookiePolicy();

            app.UseAuthentication();

            app.UseMvc();
        }
    }
}
```

I've tried both a gmail, and an outlook emails and checking spam folders; my sendgrid account says no emails have been sent at all.

Edit: My error was that I confused what the api key was. If you did not copy something the second you created the key  you will not have the right thing. it is not the name you give it is somethimg like SG_XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX and its really long.

Comment: Did try with breakpoint set in the Execute/SendEmailAsync methods of the EmailSender? Is the Sendgrid API Key given properly in the configuration?

Comment: Access [email_activity](https://app.sendgrid.com/email_activity) to check the status of your email message.

Comment: yes I did try using breakpoints. when I search in Sendgrid no email is being sent.

Comment: @SamuelWakeman did you solve this in the end comming across same issue with the boiler plate documenation ?